# Combine Onsen UI sliding menu and tabbar

Tags: mobile, slidingmenu, onsen-ui

I searched and didn't really find the right answer.

I have the sliding menu in the top left for the 'full menu' but I also want the tab bar at the top to highlight 3 or 4 specific links/pages.  How can I have them both working?  When I place the tabbar in my script, the sliding menu doesn't work right.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but did you got your answer, you can choose a best answer or you can provide your own. Regards - Ranjith

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the Tabbar element is designed to be displayed, by default, on the bottom of the page:

http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#onstabbaroverview

You can change this the position by using the attribute `position="top"`

For what concerns the combination sliding menu + tabbar I haven't had any problem to put the two elements together. Try to create a new Onsen UI Sliding Menu project and modify the file **menu.html** in this way:

```html
<ons-navigator>
       <ons-page>
            <ons-tabbar position="top">
                <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
                </ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="fav.html" active="true">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorites</span>
                </ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="settings.html" active="true">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px">Settings</span>
                </ons-tab>
            </ons-tabbar>    
            
    
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <h1>Page 1</h1>
                <ons-button
                    ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()">
                    Toggle Menu
                </ons-button>
    
                <p> Click "Toggle Menu" to close/open menu, </p>
                <p> You can also swipe the page left/right.  </p>
                <img src="images/ico_swipe_right_s.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
```

I would like to post you a screen, but I still don't have enough reputation

Comment: I think it is combining ons-navigator and ons-tabbar, and not ons-sliding-menu and ons-tabbar?

Answer (score 2):

There's no trouble on implementing sliding and tabbar.

```
<ons-sliding-menu
                  main-page="page1.html"
                  menu-page="menu.html"       
                  side="left"
                  max-slide-distance="250px"
                  var="menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="page1.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Page 1</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
<ons-tabbar position="top">
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="fav.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorites</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="settings.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Settings</span>
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-page>
    <p style="text-align:center">Home Page</p>
  </ons-page
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="fav.html">
  <ons-page>
    <p style="text-align:center">Favorites page</p>
  </ons-page
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html">
  <ons-page>
    <p style="text-align:center">Settings Page</p>
  </ons-page
</ons-template>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>


<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
      page1.html
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('fav.html', {closeMenu: true})">
      page2.html
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-template>
```

Hope this'll help. check my working [codepen](http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/WbjZZp)