# Sliding Menu with Onsen ui

Tags: onsen-ui

I've built a sliding menu with tabbar Onsen ui Like this Url:

[Combine Onsen UI sliding menu and tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337163/combine-onsen-ui-sliding-menu-and-tabbar)

But when I try to navigate to another page `onclick="Navigator.pushPage('newpage.html', {animation: 'slide'})"`.  I get an error:

> "Fail to fetch PageView from one-page element".

And on the new page, trying to pop the page with

> onclick="Navigator.popPage()"

fails as well! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That answer is quite old. Are you using Onsen UI 2?

Comment: Thanks your solution. Im not show Onsen ui 2. Right now everythink Ok.